# how to use ansible to execute shell script against gce instances

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine, ansible-2.x

how to use ansible to execute shell script against gce instances.
I have a service account and it has compute admin permission.

How to write ansible playbook so that i can execute shell scripts against all vm in my gcp project.

Below links don't help me too much
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gce_module.html#
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#gce-dynamic-inventory

I prefer ansible because it's agentless. I don't want to install any process in those vm because they're production servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out

Here is my project:

```
ansible-workplace
- .gitignore
- ansible.cfg 
- inventory.gcp.yaml
- main.yaml
- requirements.txt
```

ansible.cfg

```cfg
[defaults]
inventory = inventory.gcp.yaml
host_key_checking = False
private_key_file = /Users/<your user>/.ssh/google_compute_engine
[inventory]
enable_plugins =  host_list, script, auto, yaml, ini, toml, gcp_compute
```

inventory.gcp.yaml

```yaml
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - gcp-project1
  - gcp-project2
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /Users/<your user>/.ssh/temp-serviceaccount.json
```

main.yaml

```yaml
- name: echo
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: Manage instances
    # connection: ssh
    shell: |
      server_name=`hostname`
      echo $server_name checking legacy-endpoint-access/0.1
      leg1=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/legacy-endpoint-access/0.1)
      echo $leg1
      echo $server_name checking legacy-endpoint-access/v1beta1
      leg2=$(curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/legacy-endpoint-access/v1beta1)
      echo $leg2
    register: out
  - debug: var=out.stdout_lines
```

By default ansible will not use gcloud generated ssh key to connect to GCE instances. So you may need to do below.
"gcloud compute config-ssh" will add hostnames to your ~/.ssh/config and you can now more easily connect to gce instances and most importantly, you figure the compute key that ansible should use to connect to gce instances.
So in ansible.cfg, this line is crucial
"private_key_file = /Users//.ssh/google_compute_engine"

```
gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
gcloud compute config-ssh
ansible-playbook main.yaml
```

Now you can happily run "ansible-playbook main.yaml"